# Why should the following function have the while true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop

I wrote a function to calculate the square root, though the function must operate with the while loop at the top.

Additionally, if I type in an input value which has no square root, the function goes into infinite loop.

```
def square(x):
    return x * x

def qrt(n):
    i = 100
    
    while True:
        if square(i) != n:
            i -= 1
        else:
            return i
```

Comment: is "though" there a typo and you meant "thought"?

Also, just checking, why are you writing this? there are already builtins for finding the square root, but my guess is that you might be doing this for an assignment or just to figure it out :)

Comment: If you wrote the function why are you asking why it has a while loop?  Why did you put it there?  If this is homework, try to mentally step through what the function is doing; what is the current value of `i` at each step; why does the function only work for values of `n` which have a square root that is a whole number <= 100?

Comment: @HunnyBear Thank you so much for your comment! I 'm new to coding. I'm learning the online course myself and attempting to solve the question in class by my own function.. I figure it out now

Comment: @Anentropic Thank you for your comment! I am new to coding and am studying by myself. I print the result of each step and figure it out now. Thank you so much

Comment: @limee welcome, best of luck and enjoy your learning journey! :)

Comment: @limee you should post your working code as an answer :) 
1) if you're okay with it, we could give you a bit of a code review to see what can be better :) 
2) if someone has the same question as you, they get to see the answer you arrived at 

welcome! <3

Answer (score 0):

If you use `while(i>0):` instead of `while True:` the loop will end after i reaches 0. However, I would suggest to use `math.sqrt()` from pythons builtin math module. That would look like this:

```
import math
math.sqrt(n)
```

Comment: Thnaks! I am following a course to study.. It is a case in the course which I think can help me better understand the logic behind coding.. Thank you so much.